# rewrite rule not working on fast cgi server, PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess

This is my rule written in .htaccess on Apache 2.0 server:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.html [NC]   
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]
```

The rule is to remove the `.html` from the url.
It works fine on my local apache server, but not the fast cgi.

Any suggestions for the rule to work.

Comment: Have you enable mod_rewrite in apache?

Comment: Yes i have enabled. Some of my rules are working except this.

Comment: Does changing the 2nd line to `RewriteRule . %1 [L,R=301]` work?

Comment: No i tried ths, but its redirecting me to page not found.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file to hide html extension:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .html extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.html[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.html [L]
```